# NullReferenceException in MvcSiteMapProvider at production

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, mvcsitemapprovider

The problem is I regularly get the error at the production site (ASP.NET MVC 3) but can't reproduce this error locally.
The text of exception is:

```
ExceptionType: System.NullReferenceException
Message: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
StackTrace:
   at System.Collections.Specialized.NameObjectCollectionBase.BaseGetAllKeys()
   at System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection.get_AllKeys()
   at MvcSiteMapProvider.MvcSiteMapNode.get_MetaAttributes()
   at MvcSiteMapProvider.Web.Html.SiteMapNodeModelMapper.MapToSiteMapNodeModel(SiteMapNode node, MvcSiteMapNode mvcNode, IDictionary`2 sourceMetadata)
   at MvcSiteMapProvider.Web.Html.SiteMapPathHelper.BuildModel(MvcSiteMapHtmlHelper helper, SiteMapNode startingNode)
   at MvcSiteMapProvider.Web.Html.SiteMapPathHelper.SiteMapPath(MvcSiteMapHtmlHelper helper, String templateName)
   at ASP._Page_Views_Shared__LoggedInLayout_cshtml.Execute() in c:\Solution\Sites\Project2Site\Views\Shared\_LoggedInLayout.cshtml:line 86
   at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy()
   at System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy()
   at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage)
   at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.Write(HelperResult result)
   at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.RenderSurrounding(String partialViewName, Action`1 body)
   at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.PopContext()
   at System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass1c.<InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__19()
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter filter, ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName)
```

I have no such errors locally. Here is where I invoke `MvcSiteMap().SiteMapPath()` method:

[image]

May be somebody had the same problem before. If so please share your solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you checked out the issues page on [Github](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider) where this project is now hosted, or the discussion forum on [Codeplex](http://mvcsitemap.codeplex.com/discussions) where it was hosted previously? If so, can you add some more information regarding any dynamic nodes you may be adding. Or are all your sitemap nodes defined in the Mvc.sitemap file?

Comment: I have checked out this issue on Github and Codeplex but haven't find the one with the same stacktrace. All nodes are defined in the Mvc.Sitemap file.

Comment: Can you post the contents of your Mvc.sitemap file please. I know the theory is that what you have in here shouldn't be wrong as it works in debug but not in production, but might give some clues.

Comment: ... and the SiteMap section from within your web.config? Just thought this is probably the first place to check. Can you paste the relevant section from the web.conifig, should be something like http://pastie.org/4790913

Comment: here it is: http://pastie.org/4790927

Comment: Were you able to resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This won't answer your question directly, but may help you on your path to debugging the issue, seeing as it happens only in production and not in dev/debug.

Consider replacing your line:

```
@Html.MvcSiteMap().SiteMapPath()
```

With something like:

```
@SafeBreadCrumb()

@helper SafeBreadCrumb() {
    MvcHtmlString output;
    try
    {
        output = Html.MvcSiteMap().SiteMapPath();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        output = new MvcHtmlString(e.Message);    
    }
    <text>@output</text>
}
```

Feels a little dirty, but it's easier than grabbing the source of MvcSiteMapProvider and sticking in some logging! If it happened in debug, you wouldn't need to try this. Plus it's just a view change, so won't need a recompile.