# aps.net MVC 4 intermittent Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, iis-7

I am seeing an intermittent error on our ASP.Net MVC site hosted on production. this error is happening on all the MVC pages. Recycling the app pool and site would fix the issue but am  not able to identify the root cause

some say recycle the app pool at regular intervals, but we have excessive load and cannot do it as it would impact users.

Below is the stack trace of the error

`Object reference not set to an instance of an object. 
 StrackTrace Message:-
Server stack trace: 
   at 
System.Collections.Specialized.NameObjectCollectionBase.BaseGetAllKeys()
   at System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection.get_AllKeys()
   at System.Web.WebPages.Scope.WebConfigScopeDictionary.<>c__DisplayClass4.<.ctor>b__0() at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Lazy`1.get_Value()
   at System.Web.WebPages.Scope.WebConfigScopeDictionary.TryGetValue(Object key, Object& value)`

Comment: This appears to be similar to / a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14577735/nullreferenceexception-in-webconfigscopedictionary, but that other question was never answered.

Comment: I know the work around but am looking for a solution for this problem.